# Why am I getting this ViewType is not convertible error?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new at using Swift in general, and thus started with SwiftUI. I'm trying to make a SW FFG Dice Roller app (for personal usage) using Version 11.2.1 XCode in MacOS Mojave with Playground to get around the lack of Preview. Currently, I've noticed that I get the following error as soon as I add any additional variables to the RollView aside from the original @Binding variables. I've tried converting the rest into binding variables and creating a new observable object, but I still get the same error with Binding replacing the Int in the error. Can someone identify why I'm getting the error? Am I using too many variables here?

'RollView.Type' is not convertible to '(Binding, Binding, Binding, Binding, Binding, Binding, Binding, Binding, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int) -> RollView'

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

class Dice: ObservableObject {
    @Published var boostDiceNum: Int = 0
    @Published var abilityDiceNum: Int = 0
    @Published var proficiencyDiceNum: Int = 0
    @Published var setbackDiceNum: Int = 0
    @Published var difficultyDiceNum: Int = 0
    @Published var challengeDiceNum: Int = 0
    @Published var forceDiceNum: Int = 0
    @Published var tensidedDiceNum: Int = 0
}

struct MainView: View {

    @ObservedObject var dice: Dice

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            DiceSelectorView(boostDiceNum: self.$dice.boostDiceNum, abilityDiceNum: self.$dice.abilityDiceNum, proficiencyDiceNum: self.$dice.proficiencyDiceNum, setbackDiceNum: self.$dice.setbackDiceNum, difficultyDiceNum: self.$dice.difficultyDiceNum, challengeDiceNum: self.$dice.challengeDiceNum, forceDiceNum: self.$dice.forceDiceNum, tensidedDiceNum: self.$dice.tensidedDiceNum)
            .offset(x: -120, y: 0)
            RollView(boostDiceNum: self.$dice.boostDiceNum, abilityDiceNum: self.$dice.abilityDiceNum, proficiencyDiceNum: self.$dice.proficiencyDiceNum, setbackDiceNum: self.$dice.setbackDiceNum, difficultyDiceNum: self.$dice.difficultyDiceNum, challengeDiceNum: self.$dice.challengeDiceNum, forceDiceNum: self.$dice.forceDiceNum, tensidedDiceNum: self.$dice.tensidedDiceNum)
        }
    }
}

struct DiceSelectorView: View {

    @Binding var boostDiceNum: Int
    @Binding var abilityDiceNum: Int
    @Binding var proficiencyDiceNum: Int
    @Binding var setbackDiceNum: Int
    @Binding var difficultyDiceNum: Int
    @Binding var challengeDiceNum: Int
    @Binding var forceDiceNum: Int
    @Binding var tensidedDiceNum: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 10) {
            HStack {
                Button(
                    action: {
                        if (self.boostDiceNum > 0) {
                            self.boostDiceNum -= 1
                        }
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("-")
                    }
                )
                Text("Boost\nDice: \(boostDiceNum)")
                Button(
                    action: {
                        self.boostDiceNum += 1
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("+")
                    }
                )
            }
            HStack {
                Button(
                    action: {
                        if (self.abilityDiceNum > 0) {
                            self.abilityDiceNum -= 1
                        }
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("-")
                    }
                )
                Text("Ability\nDice: \(abilityDiceNum)")
                Button(
                    action: {
                        self.abilityDiceNum += 1
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("+")
                    }
                )
            }
            HStack {
                Button(
                    action: {
                        if (self.proficiencyDiceNum > 0) {
                            self.proficiencyDiceNum -= 1
                        }
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("-")
                    }
                )
                Text("Proficiency\nDice: \(proficiencyDiceNum)")
                Button(
                    action: {
                        self.proficiencyDiceNum += 1
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("+")
                    }
                )
            }
            HStack {
                Button(
                    action: {
                        if (self.setbackDiceNum > 0) {
                            self.setbackDiceNum -= 1
                        }
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("-")
                    }
                )
                Text("Setback\nDice: \(setbackDiceNum)")
                Button(
                    action: {
                        self.setbackDiceNum += 1
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("+")
                    }
                )
            }
            HStack {
                Button(
                    action: {
                        if (self.difficultyDiceNum > 0) {
                            self.difficultyDiceNum -= 1
                        }
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("-")
                    }
                )
                Text("Difficulty\nDice: \(difficultyDiceNum)")
                Button(
                    action: {
                        self.difficultyDiceNum += 1
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("+")
                    }
                )
            }
            HStack {
                Button(
                    action: {
                        if (self.challengeDiceNum > 0) {
                            self.challengeDiceNum -= 1
                        }
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("-")
                    }
                )
                Text("Challenge\nDice: \(challengeDiceNum)")
                Button(
                    action: {
                        self.challengeDiceNum += 1
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("+")
                    }
                )
            }
            HStack {
                Button(
                    action: {
                        if (self.forceDiceNum > 0) {
                            self.forceDiceNum -= 1
                        }
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("-")
                    }
                )
                Text("Force\nDice: \(forceDiceNum)")
                Button(
                    action: {
                        self.forceDiceNum += 1
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("+")
                    }
                )
            }
            HStack {
                Button(
                    action: {
                        if (self.tensidedDiceNum > 0) {
                            self.tensidedDiceNum -= 1
                        }
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("-")
                    }
                )
                Text("Ten-Sided\nDice: \(tensidedDiceNum)")
                Button(
                    action: {
                        self.tensidedDiceNum += 1
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("+")
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RollView: View {

    @Binding var boostDiceNum: Int
    @Binding var abilityDiceNum: Int
    @Binding var proficiencyDiceNum: Int
    @Binding var setbackDiceNum: Int
    @Binding var difficultyDiceNum: Int
    @Binding var challengeDiceNum: Int
    @Binding var forceDiceNum: Int
    @Binding var tensidedDiceNum: Int

    @State private var success: Int
    @State private var advantage: Int
    @State private var triumph: Int
    @State private var failure: Int
    @State private var threat: Int
    @State private var despair: Int
    @State private var lightSideForcePoints: Int
    @State private var darkSideForcePoints: Int
    @State private var d10: Int

    @State private var rollPreResult: String = ""

    func roll() -> Void {
        var boostDiceRoll: Int
        var abilityDiceRoll: Int
        var proficiencyDiceRoll: Int
        var setbackDiceRoll: Int
        var difficultyDiceRoll: Int
        var challengeDiceRoll: Int
        var forceDiceRoll: Int
        var tensidedDiceRoll: Int

        success = 0
        advantage = 0
        triumph = 0
        failure = 0
        threat = 0
        despair = 0
        lightSideForcePoints = 0
        darkSideForcePoints = 0
        d10 = 0

        rollPreResult = ""

        for _ in 1...self.boostDiceNum {
            boostDiceRoll = Int.random(in: 1...6)
            if boostDiceRoll == 3 {
                success += 1
            } else if boostDiceRoll == 4 {
                success += 1
                advantage += 1
            } else if boostDiceRoll == 5 {
                advantage += 2
            } else if boostDiceRoll == 6 {
                advantage += 1
            }
        }

        for _ in 1...self.abilityDiceNum {
            abilityDiceRoll = Int.random(in: 1...8)
            if abilityDiceRoll == 2 || abilityDiceRoll == 3 {
                success += 1
            } else if abilityDiceRoll == 4 {
                success += 2
            } else if abilityDiceRoll == 5 || abilityDiceRoll == 6{
                advantage += 1
            } else if abilityDiceRoll == 7 {
                success += 1
                advantage += 1
            } else if abilityDiceRoll == 8 {
                advantage += 2
            }
        }

        for _ in 1...self.proficiencyDiceNum {
            proficiencyDiceRoll = Int.random(in: 1...12)
            if proficiencyDiceRoll == 2 || proficiencyDiceRoll == 3 {
                success += 1
            } else if proficiencyDiceRoll == 4 || proficiencyDiceRoll == 5 {
                success += 2
            } else if proficiencyDiceRoll == 6 {
                advantage += 1
            } else if proficiencyDiceRoll >= 7 && proficiencyDiceRoll <= 9 {
                success += 1
                advantage += 1
            } else if proficiencyDiceRoll == 10 || proficiencyDiceRoll == 11 {
                advantage += 2
            } else if proficiencyDiceRoll == 12 {
                triumph += 1
            }
        }

        for _ in 1...self.setbackDiceNum {
            setbackDiceRoll = Int.random(in: 1...6)
            if setbackDiceRoll == 3 || setbackDiceRoll == 4{
                failure += 1
            } else if setbackDiceRoll == 5 || setbackDiceRoll == 6 {
                threat += 1
            }
        }

        for _ in 1...self.difficultyDiceNum {
            difficultyDiceRoll = Int.random(in: 1...8)
            if difficultyDiceRoll == 2 {
                failure += 1
            } else if difficultyDiceRoll == 3 {
                failure += 2
            } else if difficultyDiceRoll >= 4 && difficultyDiceRoll <= 6{
                threat += 1
            } else if difficultyDiceRoll == 7 {
                threat += 2
            } else if difficultyDiceRoll == 8 {
                failure += 1
                threat += 1
            }
        }

        for _ in 1...self.challengeDiceNum {
            challengeDiceRoll = Int.random(in: 1...12)
            if challengeDiceRoll == 2 || challengeDiceRoll == 3 {
                failure += 1
            } else if challengeDiceRoll == 4 || challengeDiceRoll == 5 {
                failure += 2
            } else if challengeDiceRoll == 6 || challengeDiceRoll == 7 {
                threat += 1
            } else if challengeDiceRoll == 8 || challengeDiceRoll == 9 {
                failure += 1
                threat += 1
            } else if challengeDiceRoll == 10 || challengeDiceRoll == 11 {
                threat += 2
            } else if challengeDiceRoll == 12 {
                despair += 1
            }
        }

        for _ in 1...self.forceDiceNum {
            forceDiceRoll = Int.random(in: 1...12)
            if forceDiceRoll <= 6 {
                darkSideForcePoints += 1
            } else if forceDiceRoll == 7 {
                darkSideForcePoints += 2
            } else if forceDiceRoll == 8 || forceDiceRoll == 9 {
                lightSideForcePoints += 1
            } else {
                lightSideForcePoints += 2
            }
        }

        for _ in 1...self.tensidedDiceNum {
            tensidedDiceRoll = Int.random(in: 1...10)
            d10 += tensidedDiceRoll
        }

        if success > 0 {
            rollPreResult += "\(success) Success\n"
        }
        if advantage > 0 {
            rollPreResult += "\(advantage) Advantage\n"
        }
        if triumph > 0 {
            rollPreResult += "\(triumph) Triumph\n"
        }
        if failure > 0 {
            rollPreResult += "\(failure) Failure\n"
        }
        if threat > 0 {
            rollPreResult += "\(threat) Threat\n"
        }
        if despair > 0 {
            rollPreResult += "\(despair) Despair\n"
        }
        if lightSideForcePoints > 0 {
            rollPreResult += "\(lightSideForcePoints) Light Side Force Points\n"
        }
        if darkSideForcePoints > 0 {
            rollPreResult += "\(darkSideForcePoints) Dark Side Force Points\n"
        }
        if d10 > 0 {
            rollPreResult += "\(d10) d10\n"
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 200) {
            Text("SW Dice")
            //Text(rollPreResult)
            Button(
                action: {
                    //self.roll()
                },
                label: {
                    Text("Roll")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: MainView(dice: Dice()))
```

Edit: I've initialized the @State variables as so and the error disappeared.

```
@State private var success: Int = 0
@State private var advantage: Int = 0
@State private var triumph: Int = 0
@State private var failure: Int = 0
@State private var threat: Int = 0
@State private var despair: Int = 0
@State private var lightSideForcePoints: Int = 0
@State private var darkSideForcePoints: Int = 0
@State private var d10: Int = 0

@State private var rollPreResult: String = ""
```

However after uncommenting the rest of the code in RollView, every time I try to run self.roll() by clicking on the roll button, Playground crashes. Does anyone know why?

Edit 2: Eventually fixed this by converting all the state variables into published variables and placed them into an observable object. I know this is not quite appropriate for variables only used in one view, but I will leave it like that for now.

Comment: Not a solution but a proposal: I would take dice as input variable for rollview, instead lots of its properties ....

Comment: All `@State` properties in `RollView` must be initialised

Comment: @Asperi Hi, I've initialized the state variables and the error disappeared. However, now I have a crashing problem as noted in my post edit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give all variables to Rollview, also your @State variables.